# How to programmatically link a user's Firebase project and database to a Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a Flutter application where users sign up with their Google accounts and are authenticated through Firebase Authentication. I want to allow users who have owner permissions on their Firebase projects to link their projects and databases to my application without manually entering Firebase ID and API key. However, I couldn't find a straightforward solution through Google Cloud Console or Firebase APIs.

How can I programmatically link a user's Firebase project and database to my Flutter application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to allow users who have owner permissions on their Firebase projects to link their projects and databases to my application without manually entering Firebase ID and API key.

That's not possible. The user will have to provide your app the values in the Firebase config from the console so you can call initializeApp with them.

The only exception to this is if you instead require the user to provide you with their Google account credentials and name of the project so you can authenticate an API all to get the configuration.  *However, no user who is thinking clearly will give you full control of their Google account like that.*

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/firebase-management/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps/getConfig

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to create an instance of `FirebaseOptions` from data entered by the user and then initialize using `Firebase.initializeApp` with that data?

Comment: That's essentially what I suggested you should do in my first paragraph.

Comment: hmm, i guess asking for the config file/required api keys and parameters is the only way left. Thanks Doug!